# Scheduled actions from Flow are not executed

Tags: visual-workflow, time-dependent-workflow, schedule

- I have created an Auto launched flow that schedules an action on the Task object 1 day after the Due Date(ActivityDate) to update the status to "Overdue".
- Whenever I create a Task for the past Due Date, the status is updated to Overdue as expected in almost 5 secs(expected behavior). But, when I create a Task with a Due Date as today and check it tomorrow then the status isn't updated.
- I checked in "Time-Based Workflow" and the action isn't present which implies the action must have been executed.
  I have also checked in "Paused and Failed Flow Interview" but there was no record present in this as well.

Also if you can explain what exactly "1 day after" mean? Does it mean that the flow will be executed after 24 hours or when the clock(user time in the org) ticks to 00:00 AM then any time after that scheduled actions can be executed?

**Edit 1:**
Please find below the configuration of the:
Flow Entry Condition:

[image]

Scheduled Path:
[image]

The decision for Field Update:
[image]

Entry criteria for Flow is: Task record type must be Churn Alert

Comment: Please use [edit] and show your flow's entry criteria and specification of the scheduled path

Comment: @cropredy added the relevant screenshots

Answer (score 0):

So -- I would do the following:

- Change your entry condition for the flow to be:

  ```
  AND(
    $Record.RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Churn_Alert',
    NOT(ISPICKVAL($Record.Status,'Overdue')),
    NOT(ISPICKVAL($Record.Status,'Done')),
    NOT(ISPICKVAL($Record.Status,'Rejected')),
    NOT(ISBLANK($Record.ActivityDate))
  )
  ```
- Change the entry evaluation to `Only when a Record is updated to meet the condition requirements`
- Remove the conditions for deciding whether to update the `Task.Status` to `Overdue` and just update, unconditionally
- Leave the scheduled path definition as is

This way, Salesforce will schedule the TBW (time-based workflow entry) as soon as a non-overdue/rejected/done Churn Alert task is created with an activity date

One day later, it will be marked as overdue. If it becomes done/rejected beforehand, SFDC will cancel the TBW. If the ActivityDate changes to a future value before the TBW starts, SFDC reschedules the TBW

Note that finding entries in the `Setup | Time-based Workflows` can be tricky as the filters don't always do what you expect - use the flow's API name is reliable as one approach while debugging